# Flyway: Support for older DB's

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I'm currently trying to set up some simple migration scripts for our databases. I was checking [flyway](http://flywaydb.org), which seems to be simple enough for what I need. My problem is that, for Postgres, only version 9 is supported (we're using 8.4). Is it possible to work around/fix this limitation somehow, or should I start looking for other options?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that when I run something like `mvn flyway:status`, I get the error message:

```
Flyway Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL
```

I can connect to the DB via `psql`, and I'm using the correct jdbc driver, so when I saw the requirements page in the documentation, I assumed that the version was explicitly checked by *flyway*.

Comment: What version of Flyway are you using? From the error message you posted you seem to be using an older release. Can you check again with  the latest 1.1 release? P.S.: As Frank Heikens said, there is no hard check for version 9.0, it is just the version we test with.

Comment: @Axel you're right, apparently I was using version 0.9. Now it connects without problems.

Answer (score 2):

What limitations do you encounter? Flyway is only tested on PostgreSQL version 9.0, that's it. It's not said that older PostgreSQL versions don't work. Just give it a try.

You could also setup a PostgreSQL 9.0 installation on your testbox to see if there is any difference.

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm getting an Unsupported DB exception, which I assumed was caused by the incompatible version. See my edit to the original question.

Comment: That looks like complete unsupported PostgreSQL, it doesn't mention any version number. Try a connection to version 9.0 first, just to found out what the problem is.